# How can I make a bootable UEFI Ubuntu installation USB that works with Secure Boot?

Tags: uefi, usb-installation

My computer has Secure boot enabled, and I can't disable it because changes I do to the bios settings doesn't get saved for some reason.

I want to install Ubuntu using a USB. I have heard that Ubuntu has UEFI authentication and will most likely work with Secure boot.

So I'm wondering if I can just download the official Ubuntu download from their website and use an application like UNetBootin to burn it to the USB, or if I have to take some special steps.

Comment: Microsoft requires vendors to let users turn off Secure Boot. Unless you have a smaller system that uses UEFI 32 bit to boot. What brand/model system?  If 64 bit UEFI then the Ubuntu installer will work. Some find one installer works better than another. But with Secure Boot on, you cannot use grub menu to dual boot, only UEFI boot menu.http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu 64-bit (alias amd64) iso files, for example

```
ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso
```

works when **cloned** also with secure boot (in UEFI mode).

1. From the version 16.04, the built-in **Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator**, is a cloning tool.
2. **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` is also a cloning tool: 'restore' from the iso file to the USB pendrive, and it works also in earlier versions of Ubuntu.
3. **mkusb** is another tool that can clone as well as make persistent live drives with another method. Using the grub bootloader and the signed files of the iso file makes Ubuntu work also with secure boot.

   [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#Using data from the source iso file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent#A2._Using_data_from_the_source_iso_file)

   [General description and 'how to' install mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)
4. **Solution**: It is a **Mac** computer, so I suggested **UnetBootin** and **dd** as a last resort. It turns out that Unetbootin makes a boot drive, that works with secure boot.

Comment: By "cloning", do you mean burning the image to a USB Stick? And I am on a mac currently, so I probably can't use gnome-disks and mkusb

Comment: Yes, you can say burning. The process is copying each byte as it is from the source to the target. You *can* use `dd`, which is the basic cloning tool, and available in the unix system underneath the MacOS. `dd` is very powerful but also very dangerous. It does what you tell it to do without questions, so if you tell it to wipe your family pictures ... and it is a minor typing error away. Another alternative is *UnetBootin*, but I am not sure that it will make a drive that works with secure boot. You can try, and if it fails, you can come back for a detailed description of the `dd` method.

Comment: UNetBootin worked, thanks for your help. I haven't installed Ubuntu yet, but when I am able to boot the Live version I guess I will be able to boot the real version as well.

Comment: Congratulations :-) Yes, I think the installed version will work too. But you may need some tweaking, and please ask another question here at AskUbuntu, if there are problems with the installed system.